# "Page build failed" after auto merging pull request to GitHub-Pages master branch

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, pull-request, github-app

The comments system on my Github Pages blog (https://github.com/artandsuffering/artandsuffering.github.io) creates each comment on a new branch and then creates a pull request to merge the branch to master. If I commit the request myself, the page rebuilds and works fine. But I want the requests to merge without me having to do anything, so I've tried a few Github apps like Mergify to automate the process. Mergify successfully merges the requests, but the blog doesn't update, and in my GitHub Pages settings I get a ["Page build failed" notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTjMk.png).
If I make a small change, like add a space to one of my SCSS files, and commit, the blog builds and updates fine. How can I automatically merge pull requests and have my blog build properly? My .mergify.yml looks like this:

```
    pull_request_rules:
  - name: automatic merge on CI success
    conditions:
      - author=artandsuffering
      - base=master
    actions:
      merge:
        method: merge
      delete_head_branch: {}
```

Comment: Do you have any details about why the page build actually fails? There should be no difference between what Mergify does and what your commit do.
Is there any way to get more details from GitHub about the issue behind?

Comment: I have the same issue. It happens with my organization repo.